# UITableViewCell Expandable Crash

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios6

I am facing a problem about expandable tableviewcell. It crashes when i try to expand tableviewcell.
I don't understand where app crashes. Please suggest me some solution.
Please Help Me.

My Code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   if (appDelegate.array_proj == (id)[NSNull null])
        return 0;
    else
        return [appDelegate.array_proj count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
    {
        if ([appDelegate.array_task count]==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"array task count: %d",[appDelegate.array_task count]);
            return [appDelegate.array_task count];
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell ==nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:53.0/255 green:53.0/255 blue:53.0/255 alpha:1.0];

    UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
    backgroundView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prjctcell_bg.png"];

    if (!indexPath.row)
    {
        objePro = [appDelegate.array_proj objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        cell.textLabel.text = objePro.projctname;
        appDelegate.intForPid=objePro.pojctid;

        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
        {
            cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (appDelegate.array_task != (id)[NSNull null])
        {
            objePro = [appDelegate.array_proj objectAtIndex:appDelegate.storeAppDelegateIndex];
            objeTask = [appDelegate.array_task objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

            cell.textLabel.text = objeTask.taskname;
            cell.backgroundView = nil;
            cell.accessoryView = nil;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    objePro = [appDelegate.array_proj objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    appDelegate.intForPid=objePro.pojctid;

   [appDelegate selectTask:appDelegate.intForPid];

    if (!indexPath.row)
    {
        [tblView beginUpdates];

        //only first row toggles expand/collapse
        [tblView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        NSInteger sections = indexPath.section;
        BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:sections];
        NSInteger rows;

        NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        if (currentlyExpanded)
        {
            rows = [self tableView:tblView numberOfRowsInSection:sections];
            [expandedSections removeIndex:sections];
        }
        else
        {
            [expandedSections addIndex:sections];
            rows = [self tableView:tblView numberOfRowsInSection:sections];
        }
        for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
        {
            NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:sections];
            [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
        }
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (currentlyExpanded)
        {

            [tblView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
            cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];
        }
        else
        {
            [tblView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
            cell.accessoryView =  [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];
        }
        [tblView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

It gives error:
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1070
2013-03-20 19:14:00.102 Daily Achiever[2886:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in these lines of code:

```
 [tblView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

and

```
 [tblView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

The crash that you posted was due to the first one.  In these lines, you are trying to insert/delete rows from the table, but your `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method does not change correspondingly.

It looks like you want to add/remove items from your `appDelegate.array_task` array whenever you are adding/removing cells from the table (as this is the array from which you are determining the row count).

As a side note, the line:

```
 if ([appDelegate.array_task count]==0) { 
    return 0;
 }
```

is not doing anything, because you have `else return [appDelegate.array_task count]` which means that 0 will be returned if `[appDelegate.array_task count]==0` anyway.

Comment: can u give me solution..? i tried lots of things from last two days but still facing problem

Comment: Either remove an object from your `appDelegate.array_task` whenever you 'de-expand' the table and add one to it when you 'expand' the table, or change your `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` to take in account whether or not the table is currently expanded (ie have a variable and add one to it if it is expanded, otherwise add 0).

Comment: i just solved that problem but when i click on section and cell expanded than than it display 2nd row not 1st. :(

Comment: Once again, the only thing I could think it could be is something in your data that is populating the table. The new table that is formed after an insert or remove will be exactly the same as a table that was first created with those cells added/removed.

Answer (score 0):

while adding sections use this code

```
NSArray *insertIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0],
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0],
                             nil];
```

for inserting rows

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

if u are adding two sections

```
 [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section + 1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
   [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section + 2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

same way delete sections

```
[tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:YES];
    [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section - 1] withRowAnimation:YES];
```

rows delete

```
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```